# how to use MSbuild to build a Win8 driver without Visual studio installed

Tags: msbuild, wdf

I want to build a KMDF driver by WDK8.0 without Visual Studio installed. I looked the msdn, it says the MSBuild do it.

But since the WDK8.0 doesn't contain the compiler, how I can use MSbuild to build a driver without VS2012?

Can anybody explain several words for me? How can I build a windows driver without VS2012.

Comment: MSbuild is part of the .net framework so you'll find it installed here:C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework as is csc the compiler.

Comment: csc is c# compiler. But you cannot develop drivers in C#. You need c++ compiler.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I’m aware after Microsoft stopped shipping compiler as part of wdk they add requirement to have installed Visual Studio.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh852362.aspx#_System_Requirements